# Add Parameter in object

Tags: node.js, object

I am initialize object in node js

```
let obj = {};
let count = 0;
```

now adding in object

```
obj[count].Id = ID;
```

It will give me error that Id not defined

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Javascript Multi Dimensional Object with named and numbered Index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47811605/javascript-multi-dimensional-object-with-named-and-numbered-index)

Comment: Well, you have no `0` property in your object, so `obj[count]` (which is `obj[0]`) resolves as `undefined`. You cannot assign properties to the value `undefined`.

Comment: `let obj = [{}];` ???

Comment: @JaydipJadhav now this fails for `count = 1` or any other number.

Comment: @VLAZ Obviously... I am just showing him, the way to initialize the array of object.

Comment: Thanks @JaydipJadhav it has solved my problem

Answer (score 0):

Solution is 
let obj = [{}];

now it is working fine for me

Answer (score -1):

I suppose you want to add Id property to "obj".
You can simply add it like :

```
obj["Id"] = ID;
```

Comment: I am unable to add comments.